# Darlington with 3.3V

Tags: transistors

I've been using [TIP120](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/TI/TIP120.pdf) darlington transistors to drive various motors, I apply a 5V Base-Emitter voltage, that I sometimes modulate with PWM and a resistor on the base, this works great, but **is there a same type of transistor for 3.3V?**

More generally, what is the best way to look for transistors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TIP120 will work at 3.3V as well. You do not apply a voltage to a bipolar transistors base, but you apply a current to the base. The resistor between your micro controller and the TIP120 will convert the voltage to a current. You might need to reduce the resistance your base resistor a bit at 3.3V.

Using a Darlington transistor can be effective for loads with a high voltage that are switched often, but are only switch on for a short time. If you switch a low voltage load, e.g.: a single LED, a motor running at 3.3 V volts, then bipolar transistors and especially darlingtons will be very ineffective. MOSFET can often be just as easy (or even simpler) to use and losses at the transistor will be smaller. Between collector and emitter of a Darlington transistor you will always lose around 1.2 V, no matter how much current you are switching. This is especially problematic if you are operating at high currents and low voltages. 
See for example these tutorials on how to use nFETs as a switch:
http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/arduino-tutorial9-power
http://bildr.org/2012/03/rfp30n06le-arduino/

Comment: So are there any guidelines to tell me when to use which type of transistor?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any good overview of how to pick transistors, especially because there are so many different use cases for transistors and priorities. Sometimes even combinations of different transistors are required. For each type of transistor such as nFET, pFET, npn, pnp, darlington npn, ... many different devices with different parameters exist. Try to learn more about these devices and try to calculate things such as power dissipation or average current into to the base or gate. As a rule of thumb: If you need a switch between a voltage between 0 and 12 V and ground use a nFET.

Comment: By camculate the power dissipation you mean multiply voltage drop through C-E and average current? Or the power dissipation through B-E?

Comment: Product of voltage drop through C-E (or D-S with FETs) and average current will be good enough in most cases. But if you use non-darlington bipolar transistors or you use FETs and switch at high frequencies then the current into the base/gate can be non-negligible as well. But not just FETs but also regular bipolar transistors can be more effective than darlington transistors, more current into the base is needed but the (saturation) voltage between C-E can be much smaller in regular bipolar transistors.

Answer (score 3):

A Darlington is not a very good way to drive a motor from 3.3V. The voltage drop is too high (At 3A the voltage drop could be as much as 2V, but at 2A it's typically a bit over 1V- even so it takes about 1/3 of the motor voltage typically).

It's better to use a MOSFET. You can search distributors using parametric search. For 3.3V drive you should pick one that is rated with 2.5V or 1.8V or 0.9V Vgs and look for a guaranteed Rds(on) at < 3V Vgs that is sufficiently low. For example, for a 1A motor you might want < 150mV drop so Rds(on) < 0.15\$\Omega\$ *with 3V drive*. Better 0.1 ohm to account for temperature. Also pick one with sufficient voltage capability (3.3V + one diode drop for the flyback diode), sufficient maximum current for the stalled condition. The parametric search is sloppy enough that you may have to go through several datasheets to be sure. For example, it may be rated for 2.5V drive, but Rds(on) quoted with 4.5V drive.

For example, a quick search comes up with the [Si3442CDV](http://www.vishay.com/docs/62654/si3442cdv.pdf). Consider undervoltage lockout if you use such a small package since the consequences of it turning partly on can be disastrous.

If you want to use BJTs then the best method is to use one transistor to drive another as below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBtC7q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Though if your motor current is << 1A then [Zetex/Diodes Inc](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/ZXTN25040DFH.pdf) have some transistors that can be directly driven by a micro (characterized at 1A Ic with 10mA  Ib as well as the more usual 100mA which is beyond most micros).

Again, use parametric search and check the datasheets with a fine-tooth comb.

Comment: 3.3V is the voltage i want to use to drive the base, the motor+ is typically at 12V

Comment: In that case, a Darlington is probably acceptable, but consider a MOSFET- it will run cooler and give you more voltage on the motor.

Comment: Ok i'll give them a try, but with a MOSFET should i drive the voltage not the current? So no extra resistor?

Comment: Spehro, just a beginner's pondering: could you as well put R2 to the emitter of Q1, so that Q1 & Q2 could be seen (and packaged) as one unit, somewhat akin to a (four-legged -- or even a normal 3-legged, perhaps with some bigger R3 built-in) PNP Sziklai pair?

Comment: @Sz. This would probably be a reasonable approach if MOSFETs didn't exist, but with the availability of [cheap low voltage MOSFETs](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3401.pdf) such as the one I mentioned above you can get better efficiency with just one inexpensive common active part.

Comment: Thanks, sure. It was just meant to be in the context of your nice arrangement on the premise of "If you want to use BJTs".

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a link to the TIP120 datasheet, so I'll take it on face value this is a darlington transistor, presumably NPN.

The advantages of two transistors arranged in a darlington configuration is that the overall gain is the product of the two individual gains.  However, one drawback of this approach is that the saturation voltage will be much higher than for a single transistor.  This makes a darlington inappropriate for switching high current, since this current times the high saturation voltage will be dissipated as heat.  The load will also see the power supply voltage reduced by the saturation voltage.

In any case, applying 5 V between the base and emitter of a darlington transistor will blow out at least one of the B-E junctions.  If you are actually driving the base with a digital output running from a 5 V supply, then the darlington is loading the digital output to bring its voltage down.  That again is a bad idea since you don't know what current the digital output can supply, which might damage the digital output and/or the transistor.

To drive a NPN transistor, whether darlington or not, from a 5 V digital output, put a resistor between the output and the base.  Consider the B-E drop to find the voltage drop across the resistor, then calculate the resistor so that you get the desired base current.

The technique is the same for a 3.3 V digital output, just that the voltage across the resistor will be lower, so a lower resistance is needed to get the same base current.

Comment: I don't want to do any amplification, only switching (so I believe the resistor calculation you recommend doesn't apply), i thought putting 5V B-E would basically "close" the E-C switch, that's what i looks like it's doing when i control DC motors, looking to do the same with 3.3V here